# Select2 Multi-select boxes doesn't work

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

I'm useing Laravel 5.6. I could make Single select boxes
that is working fine.

I read this page

```
https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage
```

and I use this CDN

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

I pasted this code below to my blade file. I can see items and I can 
click them. but there is no multi view come out and cross mark too.

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

What is wrong my code?

Comment: your code seems right . why it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom JS file. And link it to your html:

```
<script src="YourJsFile.js"></script>
```

In `YourJsFile.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
```

Your `html` file:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
  <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
  <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Mr. @Sand Of Vega Thank you for answer. I did what you said . but its just normal looking select box. I use Laravel. Is it related?

Comment: Yes. I used it in my laravel projects. @machagr